# Extending a Windows partition by adding non-adjacent unallocated place separated by a System Reserved partition

Tags: partitioning

After removing Linux system by wiping the partition it was on I want to add the resulting unallocated space to the Windows partition. The problem is: I can't join non-adjacent partitions. See the details on this photo:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIxil.png)

I had an idea of allocating space to the System Reserved partition but it isn't extendable (I can't delete it either): [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnCfc.png)

Comment: To everyone having the same problem: I don't think it's possible to do this without reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just formatting it as a new partition.

I tried recently to overcome the same issue for the same reason using different tools such as gparted without success. After trying hard enough I succeeded in mangling up the drive to the point that I had to reinstall Windows.

I've been told that Paragon Hard Disk Manager can actually move those unmovable partitions without problems, at least the MacOS version, but haven't tested it myself. The product description does mention split/merge and redistributing free space, which sounds promising.

[It's also available for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-windows/#). It's a paid product. There might be a free tryout, but should you try it I'd recommend doing a full system backup first; or at least backing up your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is:

1. Unallocated space
2. System Reserved partition
3. The C disk.

In order to merge the unallocated space into C, you need to:

- Boot using a partition editor boot USB (Not into Windows!)
- Move the System Reserved partition to the top of the disk.
  The unallocated space will now move to between it and C.
- Move C on top of the unallocated space.
  The unallocated space will now move to after C.
- You may now boot into Windows and use Disk Management to increase the
  size of C.

Before starting with the above, take careful backups, as errors may
render Windows unbootable. I suggest taking a full disk image as
backup using a tool such as
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).
You could also
[Create Windows PE or Linux Bootable Media with AOMEI Backupper](https://www.ubackup.com/help/create-bootable-disk.html)
to restore the image in the worst case, and test if it can see the
backup disk from boot.

Comment: That was what I tried to do. For some reason in my case the reserved partition simply wouldn't budge. I didn't try any specific partition editor boot disks, tho, I was simply booting a lightweight Debian distro.

Comment: @Peregrino69: Try [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.diskpart.com/free-partition-manager.html).

Comment: if I ever find myself in that situation again, I'm keeping it in mind :-)